# How to declare a variable in header file to be used in two .cpp?

Tags: c++, syntax

My target module is an executable to be built from `X.cpp` and `Y.cpp`, both these two files need a common `.h` file:

```
extern HANDLE hPipe;
extern IMediaSample *pSave = NULL;
```

But when I build the module, I got an error saying :

```
Y.obj : error LNK2005: "struct IMediaSample * pSave" (?pSave@@3PAUIMediaSample@@A) already defined in X.obj
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
extern IMediaSample *pSave = NULL;
```

This is not just a declaration. This will define `pSave` to `NULL`. Since both `.cpp` include the `.h`, this variable will be defined in 2 translation units, which causes the conflict.

You should just rewrite it as

```
extern IMediaSample *pSave;
```

in the `.h`, then add `IMediaSample *pSave = NULL;` in exactly one of the `.cpp`s.

Answer (score 0):

try using ifndef statement. define a variable unique to each header file you create then while including use something like:

```
#ifndef commonh
include common.h
#endif
```

Comment: Include guards protect you from including a header multiply *in the same source file*, not in different ones.