# How to make a constant or variable accessible in entire program

Tags: c++, qt, global-variables

I would like to have access to constant/variable of desktop width and height in entire program.

This is how I do it - add this code to every .h file of my program and then use it normally.

```
#include <QDesktopWidget>  
QDesktopWidget desktop;
int desktopHeight = desktop.geometry().height();
int desktopWidth = desktop.geometry().width();
```

I know it is not a good way how to do it. I tried to make one special `desktopSize.h` and then include to required parts of my program. But I was not successful.

What should be in header file like this one which I need?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548797/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-header-file-to-be-used-in-two-cpp

Comment: This is not my case, I'm trying to do something else. @NathanielJohnson

Comment: What are you going to do if the size of the desktop changes after the program starts?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you have tried and what specific problems you are having.

Comment: Well I tought about that, but first I want to make it at least like this :) @CaptainObvlious

Comment: Runtime error : QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget @NathanielJohnson

Comment: Is my question seriously that bad?? thx for help btw

Comment: Yet another reason not to do this. You have to make sure that you have a QApplication before you try to use QDesktopWidget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really do not want to use that particular approach and include that code in all translation units. If you did each one would include two variables named `desktopWidth` and `desktopHeight` causing duplicate symbol errors during link time. It will also make it difficult to manage updating them if the size of the desktop changes after the application starts. If you really want to provide global variables holding the size of the desktop you should place them in a single .cpp file and place `extern` declarations in a single header file that is included when needed.

Header file (`GlobalDesktopInfo.h`)

```
#ifndef GLOBALDESKTOPINFO_H
#define GLOBALDESKTOPINFO_H

extern int desktopHeight;
extern int desktopWidth;

#endif GLOBALDESKTOPINFO_H
```

Source file (`GlobalDesktopInfo.cpp`)

```
#include "GlobalDesktopInfo.h"
int desktopHeight = 0;
int desktopWidth = 0;
```

You will also need to initialize it at the earlier point reasonably possible. I suggest doing this in your `main()` function.

```
#include "GlobalDesktopInfo.h"
// other includes

int main()
{
    QApplication app;

    QDesktopWidget desktop;
    desktopHeight = desktop.geometry().height();
    desktopWidth = desktop.geometry().width();

    // other code and initialization
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to have some slots in a class which return the desired values and use Qt's Signal/slot mechanism to access them from other classes.

Just make a signal in the target class, connect it to a slot in the class containing the slots and make a connection between two objects of the classes. This way you can access them in every class you like by connecting a signal to a slot returning that value and just emitting the signal and getting the returned value.

For example you can have a class like :

```
class DesktopInformation 
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    DesktopInformation(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~DesktopInformation();

    QDesktopWidget desktop;

public slots:

      int getWidth()
      {
           return desktop.geometry().width();
      }
      int getHeight()
      {
           return desktop.geometry().height();
      }
};
```

And access the desktop information from any other class like :

```
class SomeClass: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    SomeClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SomeClass();

signals:
      int getWidth();
      int getHeight();

private:

      void someFunction()
      {
           int width = getWidth();
           int heigth = getHeight();
           ...
      }
};
```

And connect the signal from an object of `SomeClass` to the slot in an object of `DesktopInformation` :

```
connect(someClass, SIGNAL(getWidth()), desktopInformation, SLOT(getWidth()));
```

In class `someClass` you can access the value returned from `getWidth` slot in `desktopInformation` by just calling the signal and using the returned value.

Note that the two objects should be in the same thread for this to work. If they are in different threads then the connection type should be of type `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` :

```
connect(someClass, SIGNAL(getWidth()), desktopInformation, SLOT(getWidth()), Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
```

Another way is two use static member functions but it is not recommended unless you have a good reason to do it :

```
class desktopInformation {
   public:
      static QDesktopWidget desktop;

      static int getWidth()
      {
           return desktop.geometry().width();
      }
      static int getHeight()
      {
           return desktop.geometry().height();
      }
};

class someClass {
   public:
      void do_something();
};
```

You can access `desktopInformation`'s static member function from `someClass` like this:

```
void someClass::do_something()
{
     int width = A::getWidth();
     ...
};
```